# Can a class have its own private PrintWriter?

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I'm writing a Table class, which stores column name and length information about a relation. The class itself doesn't store the records/tuples, however, as that information is supposed to be directly entered into a txt file via an Insert method. To make the insert method easier by not recreating a printwriter for every call, can the Table class have its own Printwriter that I can call from Table.insert? Basically,

```
public class Table{
    private String tableName;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public void Table(){
        //get table name
        writer = new PrintWriter(tableName+".txt"); 
    ...}

    public void insert(){
        //get, format, add info to file
        writer.format(formatstring, args);
    }
```

Are there any flaws with this use of PrintWriter?

Comment: Your instantiation of `writer` should probably be in a constructor. I believe `tableName` will be null in the above code resulting in either an error or a filename of simply `.txt`

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be creating a `PrintWriter` for each call. Just make sure you do what @CollinD suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes, you can hold a `PrintWriter` member. Since you're dealing with a filesystem here, there are all sorts of things that could go wrong when creating the `PrintWriter`. It may be a better practice to open it in a constructor (instead of inlining it in the member's definition) to allow proper exception handling.

Comment: Do you mean open it in the constructor instead of defining it there? Or did you answer before I edited the code?

Comment: @PeterSon yup, I answered before you edited the question

Comment: @PeterSon yup, it should be